# Opening a file and enable dropdownlist on single click event of linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I want to open a file from given path and enable a dropdownlist on click event of linkbutton. But only file gets opened dropdownlist is not enabled.Both the controls are placed in a gridview. Have tried keeping the two task in function and then calling on clickevent, still didn't work. Even when i tried to display a popup and open a file on click event it didn't work.

```
protected void lnkvwReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkvwReport = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row1 = (GridViewRow)lnkvwReport.Parent.Parent;
    DropDownList ddlfeedback = ((DropDownList)row1.FindControl("ddlfeedback"));
    ddlfeedback.Enabled = true;  //DOESN'T WORK
    //FILE OPENING PART - WORKS
    string savepath="PATH_TO_FILE";
    string filename=savepath+"Report";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","inline;filename=report");
    Response.ContentType="application/vns.ms-excel";
    Response.Flush();
    Response.WriteFile(filename);
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: No replies. So is it not possible?

Comment: Not exactly; you're trying to produce two different HTTP responses for a single HTTP request: one containing the updated page with its viewstate, and one containing the file to download. I've marked this as a duplicate because this is already addressed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926409/start-a-file-download-after-a-postback).